# Scrapy find all links with different(similar) class

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to scrap links with certain class "post-item post-item-xxxxx". But since the class is different in each, how can I capture all of them?

```
<li class="post-item post-item-18887"><a
href="http://example.com/archives/18887.html" title="Post1"</a></li>
<li class="post-item post-item-18883"><a href="http://example.com/archives/18883.html" title="Post2"</a></li>
```

my code:

## scrap all the cafe links from example.com

```
class DengaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cafes'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://example.com/archives/8136.html',
    ]

    rules = [
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=('^http://example\.com/archives/\d+.html$'),
                unique=True
            ),
            follow=True,
            callback="parse_items"
        )
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        cafelink = response.css('post.item').xpath('//a/@href').extract()
        if cafelink is not None:
            print(cafelink)
```

the .css part is not working, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Xpath has the `contains()` method for this, so you might try this:

```
cafelink = response.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'post-item-')]//a/@href").extract()
```

Also be careful when using `//` in xpath. It makes xpath starts the search in the document root, no matter where it currently is.

Comment: //* gives me syntax error, tried few different ways still same error

Comment: sorry, forgot a quotation mark, edited my answer to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample run for the above html in `scrapy shell`:

```
>>> from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
>>> response = HtmlResponse(url="Test HTML String", body='<li class="post-item post-item-18887"><a href="http://example.com/archives/18887.html" title="Post1"</a></li><li class="post-item post-item-18883"><a href="http://example.com/archives/18883.html" title="Post2"</a></li>', encoding='utf-8')
>>> 
>>> cafelink = response.css('li.post-item a::attr(href)').extract_first()
>>> cafelink
'http://example.com/archives/18887.html'
>>> 
>>> cafelink = response.css('li.post-item a::attr(href)').extract()
>>> cafelink
['http://example.com/archives/18887.html', 'http://example.com/archives/18883.html']
```

Comment: it worked! "yield" only return 1st result, "print" shows the entire list. any idea why?

Comment: `yield` has nothing to do with returning `1st` result, if you `extract_first()` then only `1st` result is extracted, if you use `extract()` then `all results` gets extracted.

Answer (score 0):

If all the items you want also have the "post-item" class then why do you need to capture them by their other class? In case you still need to do that, try the "starts with" CSS selector:

`response.css('li[class^="post-item post-item-"]')`

Documentation [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings).

Comment: thank you. I should've gone with css instead xpath from the start.